# Зачем в Comparator есть метод equals()?

Tags: java, интерфейс, java-8, лямбда-выражение

Итак, метод `equals()` в функциональном интерфейсе `Comparator`.

Не пойму вот. Вроде бы методы класса `Object` нельзя определять в интерфейсах (потому что реализация всегда берётся от `Object`). Но зачем класс `Comparator` тогда содержит в себе этот метод? Причём, он даже не `default`!

Исходя из того, что я нашёл в интернете, я решил, что он нужен для сравнения объектов Comparator. Но как мне его реализовывать, если я собираюсь использовать Comparator исключительно с лямбдами?

И ещё вопрос: каким образом в Comparator два не `static` и не `default` метода, а он является функциональным интерфейсом (я имею в виду методы `compare()` и этот злосчастный `equals()`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`equals` служит в данном случая для сравнения самих компараторов.

В `Comparator` `equals` может возвращать `true` даже для компараторов разных типов, если они задают одинаковое отношение порядка. Вот цитата из javadoc к `equals`, который для того и добавлен, чтобы описать это изменение контракта:

> Additionally, this method can return
> true *only* if the specified object is also a comparator
> and it imposes the same ordering as this comparator

Реализовывать его необязательно (а случае, если используете лямбды, то и невозможно). Реализация унаследованная из Object (т.е. сравнения по ссылке) подойдет в подавляющем большинстве случаев.

Что касается функциональных интерфейсов и двух абстрактных методов, то public методы из `Object` не учитываются. Вот цитата из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html):

> If an interface declares an abstract method overriding one of the public methods of java.lang.Object, that also does not count toward the interface's abstract method count since any implementation of the interface will have an implementation from java.lang.Object or elsewhere.

Comment: Спасибо. Но да, я что-то такое и подозревал. Любопытно конечно, добавили получается только для того, что написать об этом в документации... Забавно. Интересно так же то, что в самом интерфейсе Comparator отсутствуют какие-либо комментарии и пояснения (что довольно странно для стандартной библиотеки), и приходится лезть в javadoc.